# What algorithm has the best runtime?

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, recursive-algorithms

Suppose you are choosing between the following three algorithms:

Algorithm A solves problems by dividing them into five subproblems of half the size, recursively solving each subproblem, and then combining the solutions in linear time.

Algorithm B solves problems of size n by recursively solving two subproblems of size n − 1
and then combining the solutions in constant time.

Algorithm C solves problems of size n by dividing them into nine subproblems of size n/3,
recursively solving each subproblem, and then combining the solutions in O(n^2) time.

What are the running times of each of these algorithms (in big-O notation), and which would you
choose?

So, for A I guess thats O(n*log(n)), because of T(n) = 5T(n/2) + O(n)

For C, it should be O(n^2) - applying Master Theorem

And for B Im not quite sure since: We have a tree with n-depth. Just O(n)? Thank You very much :)

Comment: I don't know what "Master Theorem" you have in mind for algorithm C, but your estimate looks right. For B, it's going to be $O(2^n)$: you have a tree of height $n$ and, even if you assume the time to combine partial solutions is negligible, you are asking how many leaves does the tree have.

Answer (score 0):

The recurrences for the algorithms $A, B$ and $C$ are:

$$ A(n) = 5A\left( \frac{n}{2} \right) + n $$
$$ B(n) = 2 B(n - 1) + 1 $$
$$ C(n) = 9C\left( \frac{n}{3} \right) + n^2 $$

The bounds of these recurrences are:
$$ A(n) = \Theta\left(n^{\log_2 5}\right) $$
$$ B(n) = \Theta \left( 2^n \right) $$
$$ C(n) = \Theta \left( n^2 \log_3 n \right) $$

The most efficient algorithm in terms of complexity is $C$. Since you were unsure about $B$ we derive its solution. We expand the first few terms and find that:

$$ B(n) = 1 + 2 + 2^2 + 2^3 + 2^4 + ... + 2^n $$
$$ = \sum_{k = 0}^n 2^k = 2^{n - 1} - 1 $$

And so $B(n) = \Theta \left( 2^n \right)$. We can verify all bounds using induction.